# Made PHP CSS And HTML progress bar

Tags: php, html, css, progress-bar

I made a progress bar with PHP, CSS, and HTML. Well it works correctly but for instance a user has 6/6 stamina. The bar is going to be 6% of 100%. How would I change this? Here's the coding below..

```
<div class="progress-outer">
    <div class="progress-inner" 
    style="width: <?php echo $energy ?>%;">Energy:<?php echo $energy . '/' . $max_energy ?></div>
    </div>​
```

The CSS is..

```
.progress-outer {
background: #000000;
height: 20px;
padding: 2px;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.progress-inner {
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
background: #333333;
height: 100%;
}​
```

Comment: 6/6 tells me he has a 100%...i'm confused

Comment: anyway to get the width its energy/max_energy

Answer (score 2):

The first `<?php echo $energy ?>` should be `<?php echo ($energy/$max_energy*100) ?>`...

Comment: When I added that coding, it fixed the stamina bar, but moved some other things around?

Answer (score 1):

it would be something like this (I added some visual style for testing..you can remove the `background-color`s_

```
<?php
$max_energy = 100;
$energy = 6;
?>
<div class="progress-outer" style="border:1px solid black;background:#ff0000;width:100px">
    <div class="progress-inner" style="background:#0F0;width:<?php echo ($energy/$max_energy * 100); ?>px;">Energy:<?php echo $energy . '/' . $max_energy; ?></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: @Tommy got it to work! Also $energy & $max_energy are in a database

Comment: I understand that, I was just giving an example as to what the values would be. I see you're new...don't forget to mark Tommy's answer as correct

Comment: ahh, well thank you.. But i do have a question. When I use the 2 <div> it moved the bars upward? Even valign won't move them down? Any reasons why?

Comment: Well, when I copied your code into my test PHP file, there was some weird unicode characters that were getting displayed. I deleted the last instance of `</div>` and typed it myself and it went away. Other than that, I'd have to see more code or at least a link where I can see it. It showed up like this `â€‹`

Comment: hmm.. odd.. Well the link is. psychowars.com/psychowars/ login is..
email: test@psychowars.com
password: password

Comment: When i took out </div> it centered them again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the idea at all but I guess he want to create a progress bar based in two numbers percentage.

Here is the example (I did it in javascript so is visible):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCIKD

So the php code should be like this:

```
<?php
$current = 3;
$max = 6;
// (current / max) * 100% to obtain the percentage.
$percentage = ($current / $max) * 100;
echo "The percentage of ".$current." from ".$max." is ".$percentage;
?>
```

Hope it helps.